# mobile application was rejected in app store due to health kit framework

Tags: ios, mobile, xamarin, mobile-application

I made iOS app using Xamarin and my app is getting rejected for the following reason:

> Apps using the HealthKit framework must indicate integration with the
>   Health app in their marketing text and must clearly identify the
>   HealthKit functionality in the app's user interface

But I don't use `HealthKit` anywhere and didn't enable it. I can't find any reference of it in the code.

Has anyone had this problem before?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved it by adding in project Properties, iOS Build:
Additional Options => Additional mtouch arguments: --linkskip=HealthKit

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check on your Apple Developer Center it isn't activated it on your Application Certificates.

Comment: I disabled this framework in my Application  Certificate. I replied to resolution center that app doesn't use health kit framework. May be it must be removed somewhere in build phases?

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough a week ago had my Xamarin app rejected for the same reason. 
Although on the resolution center they asked me if the App uses the HealthKit Framework and i replied that the app does not use it. 
Was approved the next day

Comment: Can you tell me what option you choose in iOS Build ->"Linker option"?

Comment: @Vitali the **"Linker Behavior"** was **"Link Framewroks SDKs only"** . Did you try to reply to the Apple resolution center reject message? That should sort things out

Comment: i replied them that app doesn't use health kit and i didn't implement it, but it doesn't help. This is the third time my app is rejected due to this issue.

Comment: the rejection title of my app was **"Meta Data Rejected"** . Dont know if this could help you in anyway

Comment: Does anybody able to resolbe this issue, as I can't set linker to SDK framework only because of some 3rd party liberary. Also, I have uploaded a nee build with mtouch parameter "--linkskip=HealthKit", still my app got rejected 2nd time. Can anyone please guide me what more cahnges need to be done to remove the reference of HEALTHKIT framework from the application. Amy suggestion will be helpful